# Don't display items to combobox from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have defined a model in Entity Framework. Now I want to fill out the combobox from this model. But I was unsuccessful.

```
private void comboBox6_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SamenEntities c = new SamenEntities())
    {
        comboBox6.DataSource = c.sabt_como_tahsili.ToList();
        comboBox6.ValueMember = "id_vaziat_tahsili";
        comboBox6.DisplayMember = "name_vaziat_tahsili";
    }
}
```

No data is displayed in the comboBox

Comment: Can you show us the code for your combobox?

Comment: It doesn't look quite right to initialize the combobox on SelectedIndexChanged()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    using (SamenEntities c = new SamenEntities())
    {
        comboBox6.DataSource = c.sabt_como_tahsili.ToList();
        comboBox6.ValueMember = "id_vaziat_tahsili";
        comboBox6.DisplayMember = "name_vaziat_tahsili";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fill your combo box when you initialize your form. Or maybe create a `RefreshDataSources` function which will reload every data set on your form, this combo box included. Like this maybe?

```
private void RefreshDataSources()
{
   using (SamenEntities c = new SamenEntities())
    {
        #region combobox
        comboBox6.DataSource = c.sabt_como_tahsili.ToList();
        comboBox6.ValueMember = "id_vaziat_tahsili";
        comboBox6.DisplayMember = "name_vaziat_tahsili";
        #endregion

        // place other controls here
    }
}
```

But doing that in the event `SelectedIndexChanged` is not the best choice, even when it would work.

---

EDIT

Just checked the behavior of a usual microsoft combobox item.
The `SelectedIndexChanged` won't be launched if there is no items inside it, so no chance to execute your code.